# How can i get the data from an http link in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a link, that when opened in a Browser, shows some information in form of text: https://api.mcuuid.com/v1/profile/ed15e741-8ab9-46c6-b47d-63df173fede2/name
Now, I want to use the data, that would be displayed in the Browser on my Website.
In the end, I want this to be seen on MY website: {
    "username": "SpigxtPlugins",
    "live": false,
    "age": 573
}

The returned value of the link in the Browser.

Comment: Would you like to solve this with javascript (ajax calls) or server-side? (php)

Comment: `$_SERVER` or `window.location`?

Comment: server-side, otherwise I wouldn't have put PHP in my title of the Question.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix read the Question, not just the Title!

Comment: [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), or [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) (with `allow_url_fopen`), and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: it looks like json data so use `json_decode`

Comment: you want it to be seen as JSON? `I want this to be seen on MY website: { "username": "SpigxtPlugins", "live": false, "age": 573 }` if we are going to be sticklers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following any method:

1. [file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function of php and then use json_decode.
2. Use the [curl in php](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216688028-cURL-overview).

Here is the link to know how to decode the json data: [json-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Hope the links given here will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, and thank you for the link on Json-Decode!